# Ruby/Rails 6 summation during iteration

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got an App in which `User` can buy shares in a `Portfolio` through a `wallet.cash_transaction`. Now I would like to display all shareholders of the portfolio specifying the user's name and the number of shares in a given portfolio.

```
#models association
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_one  :wallet, as: :walletable
  has_many :cash_transactions, through: :wallet
end

class Portfolio < ApplicationRecord
  has_one  :wallet, as: :walletable
end

class Wallet < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :walletable, polymorphic: true

  has_many   :cash_transactions
end

class CashTransaction < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :wallet
  belongs_to :to_wallet, class_name: 'Wallet', optional: true
end
```

To display shareholders I'll need below join:

```
> portfolio = Portfolio.last

@shareholders = User.joins(:cash_transactions).where(cash_transactions: { to_wallet: portfolio.wallet }).uniq
```

Which I can use in the view by below iteration:

```
<tbody>
  <% @shareholders.each do |user| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= "#{user.first_name} #{user.last_name}" %></td>
      <td><%= user.cash_transactions.where(to_wallet: portfolio.wallet).sum(:shares_number) %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</tbody>
```

Line `user.cash_transactions.where(to_wallet: portfolio.wallet).sum(:shares_number)` is responsible for the summation of all user shares in the portfolio. This method doesn't seem very efficient to me because it seems like I'll be sum-up unnecessarily at each iteration. I imagine that when there will be hundreds of thousands of users it can be aggravating at every refresh of the page. Is there a better way to do so?

Comment: You don't need to touch every user's transactions. you need only wallet's transactions. `wallet.cash_transactions.group(:walletable_id)` looks like a good start. You should be able to filter walletables for only users and add `.sum(:shares_number)` on top, but I can't check the exact line right now.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "walletable_id" does not exist)` for `portfolio.wallet.cash_transactions.group(:walletable_id)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write SQL queries to get sum of all matched records

```
@shareholders = User.joins(:cash_transactions)
 .where(cash_transactions: { to_wallet: portfolio.wallet})
 .select("users.*, SUM(cash_transactions.shares_number) as total_shares_number")
 .group("users.id")
```

you will get all columns of `users` table and sum of total `shares_number`, Add more fields form another table as per your requirement